# VBA Copy Column and Paste Values to Last Unmodified Column

Tags: vba, excel

```
ABCDE
zx c
zx c
zx c
```

to

```
ABCDE
zx cz
zx cz
zx cz
```

So I would like to select a column and the macro moves it to Column E

Current Attempts define a range so it's not usable between different workbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said "moves to column E", I assume you meant "Copies to column E". Please try this code below

```
Sub Copy_Col()
    Dim lc As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Selection.Copy
        .Cells(1, lc + 1).PasteSpecial
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thanks

Caleeco

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit
Sub CopyColumn()
Dim LastUnmodifiedColumn as long

' no qualified workbook/worksheet below. Therefore, implicitly refers to whatever book/sheet is active'
Lastunmodifiedcolumn = cells(1, columns.count).end(xltoleft).column + 1

' if you want values only, can assign values directly without using clipboard copy/paste operations'
With selection
.value2 = .offset(0,lastunmodifiedcolumn - .column).value2
'If you want to move and not copy, uncomment next line.'
'.clearcontents

End with
End sub
```

Hope it works or helps.